# Is it possible to show the inherit relationship of two interfaces in a Visual Studio code map?

Tags: visual-studio, code-map

See the below image. `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable` but there is no arrow between them. I've already enabled all filters but still can't make then appear. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your seeing is normal behavior. C# allows for only single inheritance. Interfaces are not inherited--they're implemented. You won't have an inheritance arrow for interfaces in light of that definition.